How do I add -Cinstrument-coverage to .cargo/config.toml for Each Platform?
I'm working on a pgrx extension that requires this .cargo/config.toml entry to build on macOS:
[target.'cfg(target_os="macos")']
# Postgres symbols won't be available until runtime
rustflags = ["-Clink-arg=-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup"]

In order to instrument test coverage, I need to add -Cinstrument-coverage to rustflags — but only when generating coverage profiles. Right now I have a hinky shell script that does the right thing:
export RUSTFLAGS="-Cinstrument-coverage"
if [ "$(uname -o)" = "Darwin" ]; then
    export RUSTFLAGS="-Clink-arg=-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup $RUSTFLAGS"
fi

But I would think I could do the same thing by enabling a configuration while running tests and having it load the proper config from .cargo/config.toml for the current (target) platform. How do I do that?

profile rustflags are currently unstable, if that's of any help?

@eggyal Maybe? I don't think there's a separate profile for test coverage, is there? What would it look like?

No, there isn't.  But you can define one, or just apply it to/use the dev profile?

I would very much appreciate an example in an answer. :-)
